# Как лучше заполнять таблицу DataTable?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

1. Извлечь SqlDataReader, по нему создать схему таблицы (выбрать все
   необходимые свойства столбцов), дальше с помощью цикла заполнить
   таблицу, копируя строки из SqlDataReader
2. Извлечь SqlDataReader, передать его в качестве параметра методу
   .Load() для SqlDataTable

В чём отличие этих методов и как лучше делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В 1-м случае вы можете более полно контролировать процесс, например не грузить какие-то столбцы, или загрузить не существующие в исходной выборке столбцы какими-то виртуальными данными, генерируя их по ходу дела, основываясь, например, на данных из других столбцов и/или каких-то внешних данных, или выполнить какие-то хитрые преобразования типов, пропустить какие-то нежелательные строки, и т.п. Думаю, однако, что на практике такой способ (прямое чтение из `SqlDataReader`) чаще применяется не для загрузки `DataTable`, а для загрузки данных напрямую в различные объекты, списки, словари, и т.п.

Во 2-м случае таблица загружается из `SqlDataReader` "как есть". Такой способ может пригодиться, когда `SqlDataReader` возвращает несколько результатов, некоторые из которых вам нужно загрузить в `DataTable`, а другие обработать как-то иначе. Также обратите внимание, что в 1-м случае для продвижения к следующему результату вам нужно вызывать `NextResult()`, тогда как после `Load()` таблицы из `SqlDataReader` вызов `NextResult()` происходит автоматически.

Если вам не нужны никакие преобразования данных, вы можете также заполнить таблицу с помощью `SqlDataAdapter`:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

SqlCommand cmd = ...;
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
```